# 14.04 LTS on HP EliteBook 8740w with NVIDIA and DreamColor

Tags: drivers, 14.04, nvidia

I have been running Ubuntu 13.04 for quite some time and though I would upgrade to 14.04 LTS as I also wanted to migrate to a larger SSD disk.

In the past it was tricky to install Ubuntu because the HP Dreamcolor display in my HP EliteBook 8740w needed the NVIDIA drivers. This was solved using an external monitor to install Ubuntu and then install the proprietary NVIDIA drivers.

When trying to install 14.04 LTS, this procedure doesn't work - all screens (VGA, Display-port and built in) remain black except for some funny coloured characters.

I though I could install the old 13.04 and then perform an upgrade. This has also proven to be tricky as "13.04 it is no longer supported" and a lot of references to packages doesn’t seem to be valid any more. I get 13.04 installed but have not managed to get the NVIDIA driver working. (It works beautifully on my existing installation (other hdd)).

Advice appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I am going to answer my own question as nobody else did. What I didn't know then and what I know now is when installing Ubuntu there are a few fundamental settings, like keyboard layout, language (I knew that). There is also an option called "nomodeset" which will install Ubuntu using a generic graphic mode and driver which is supported by probably all graphical subsystems. Choosing this will make it possible to install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (and other versions) and once installed it is easy to get the driver for the Nvidia graphics working.